# Linq Select Substring WHERE VALUE of Column has 1

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have here Table of Schedule then I want to select this table into a row with this result

```
Code    Days
CS1     MT           AS Monday and Tuesday
CS2     WTH          AS Wednesday and Tuesday
ENG1    MWF          AS Monday, Wednesday and Friday
ENG1    SAT1         AS Saturday 1
```

I have tried this on LINQ query then my result was this

[image]

using LINQ

```
from a in Schedules
select new 
{
    a.ScheduleID,
    a.ScCode,
    Days = a.Mon == 1 ? "M" : a.Tue == 1 ? "T" : a.Wed == 1 ? "W" : a.Thu == 1 ? "TH" : a.Fri == 1 ? "F" : a.Sat == 1 ? "SAT" : a.Sun == 1 ? "SUN" : "NO SCHEDULE"
}
```

which didn't give my expected result.

Does anyone have an idea about this? Iv'e prepared the materials here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ef5d/1

Thanks.

Comment: Your table has for rows, you get four rows, your massive ternary statement short circuits on the first true condition.

Comment: Is WTH really supposed to be Wednesday and Thursday?

Comment: ahh, your'e right that's what my friend told me too, but how can i solve this? any suggest sir? or im wrong on my database structure?

Comment: yes @Kevin because Tuesday and Thursday have the same first letter so im using TH on Thursday. :D

Comment: Your pain point is that your design is bad. Consequently your code is going to be ugly. You need to coalesce the values unless there is no value, then you choose "No Schedule". That's going to look ugly and LINQ won't help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree in part with @shoe in that the design is most likely the largest part of the problem, I also believe in meeting people where they are and helping them as they are. With that being said, here is your answer:

```
from a in Schedules
select new
{
    a.ScheduleID,
    a.ScCode,
    Days = GetDays(a)
};
```

What you are looking for lies within the following method:

```
private string GetDays(Schedule schedule)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (schedule.Mon == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("M");
    }

    if (schedule.Tue == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("T");
    }

    if (schedule.Wed == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("W");
    }

    if (schedule.Thu == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("TH");
    }

    if (schedule.Fri == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("F");
    }

    if (schedule.Sat == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("SAT");
    }

    if (schedule.Sun == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("SUN");
    }

    if (schedule.Mon1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("M1");
    }

    if (schedule.Tue1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("T1");
    }

    if (schedule.Wed1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("W1");
    }

    if (schedule.Thu1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("TH1");
    }

    if (schedule.Fri1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("F1");
    }

    if (schedule.Sat1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("SAT1");
    }

    if (schedule.Sun1 == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("SUN1");
    }

    if (stringBuilder.Length == 0)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("NO SCHEDULE");
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Awesome this answer fits on my project. thank you somuch more power to you sir.